# Flex: How do you use pushView() to access a specific state of a certain viewClass?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, state, flex-spark

From a viewClass called TheFirstView I want to "move" to a viewClass called TheSecondView with the state SpecificState.

I know how to get to the TheSecondView, the code is:
`navigator.pushView(TheSecondView);`

Is there a way to specify using pushView() that you want to "move" to SpecificState in TheSecondView?

Comment: You can pass data into the view; which is the second property of the pushView method.  You can make that data a string representing the state you want the view to be in and when the view is activated set it to that state.  I'm not sure how I feel about this approach, as--in theory--one view should not know details about the other.

Comment: Would the code look like this: `navigator.pushView(TheSecondView, 'currentState="SpecificState"');`

Comment: In addition, how would you get this string to "activiated" in TheSecondView?

Comment: The code would look like `navigator.pushView(TheSecondView, 'SpecificState')` .  In the a viewActivated http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html#event:viewActivate event listener; do something like this: `currentState = data;`

Comment: Can you call "currentState=data;" in viewActivated? I tried doing this (and it doesn't work, I get syntax errors): `<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  backgroundAlpha="0" xmlns:MyComp="components.*" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="TheSecondView" creationComplete="initApp(event)"  viewActivate="currentState=data;">`

Comment: Create a method, l9ike you did for the creationComplete event.  What are you syntax errors?

Comment: I put currentState=data; into a method and it now works. Thanks!

Comment: I added a formal answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data into the view; which is the second property of the pushView method, like this:

```
navigator.pushView(TheSecondView, 'SpecificState')
```

Inside the view, you can listen for the [viewActivated](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html#event%3aviewActivate) event to change the state:

Add the listener:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" viewActivate="onViewActivated()">
```

And in some ActionScript code, implement the listener like this:

```
protected function onViewActivated():void{
 currentState=data;
}
```